# run a method of a controller in the application view or render from app layout to another controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I hope people can understand me.. sorry if not. I'll try to explain this the best I can.
I touch rails here and then every 8-9 months one or two times.. so I forget a lot of things so sorry if this question response is way to obvios, I honestly did my search around and did not find the same issue.(or so I thought)

I'm using rails with  twitter bootstrap in one of my apps, the menu on the top and the right side have elements that I want to create dynamically as I create new rows in the database.
example:
rss feed 1
rss feed 2
....
as of now the menu is static.. I have to enter it manually in the code.
I'm trying to do this dynamically, such will be very easy if it was all in the same controler, but since my menu view is on the application controller, i'm having issues accessing from there my rssfeed controller to get a list of rows and and auto create the menu.
here is what I have:
on the application.html.erb layout:

```
<div class="container nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <%= render 'rssfeeds/menu' %>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

on the rssfeeds/menu
called _menu.html.erb

```
<% unless  @my_rssfeeds.nil?  %>
  <% @rssfeeds.each do |feed| %>
    <li><%= link_to "#{feed.title}", "rssfeeds/#{feed.id}"  %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

so first I tried to put the _menu on the application controller view folder but though if this was calling the rssfeed controller to put it inside the rssfeed view folder this is why I call it with the path.

Any ideas what is the best way to do this?

here is another example from the log, it may help:

```
 Rendered rssfeeds/_feed.html.erb (2.2ms)
 Rendered rssfeeds/show.html.erb within layouts/application (6.5ms)
 Rendered common/_menu.html.erb (0.4ms)
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 614ms

 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
 1: <% @rssfeeds.each do |feed| %>
 2:   <li><%= link_to "#{feed.title}", "rssfeeds/#{feed.id}"  %></li>
 3: <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a convention saying that if some partial is used by more controllers, then its location is `app/views/common/_partial_name`. Now, wherever that partial is needed, it is accessible by `<%= render 'common/partial_name' %>`

Comment: Hello thanks for the response, I can move it there.. but what I need to access from that partial and I can't is the actually method from rssfeed controller.. from it.. will this do the trick as well?

Comment: ok I did the change.. still my data is empty. not picking up the values.

Comment: It is, because every time you want to render that partial, you also need to fill `@my_rssfeeds` with your rss feeds. If you render `ApplicationController#index` or `RssFeedsController#index`, it is essential for both of them.

Comment: I know that. this is why Im trying to call  def index
    @rssfeeds = Rssfeed.all
  end  from rssfeeds controller but the one rendering my menu/layout is application controller so it does not see it, I need to have application controller view my methods inside rssfeeds controller. well I just need that one itself.. to feel up my menu.

Comment: OK, I think I get it now. You want to use method from parent controller, right? Well, it is possible, but I don't think it's a good idea since you probably use render within parent and child method and that would raise `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`. I would say, for that case the easiest solution would be to put some method within your `application_controller` which provide `@rssfeeds = Rssfeed.all` and then reuse it where necessary.

Comment: yes something like that... I did try to put: @rssfeeds = Rssfeed.all  in the application controller, but still I get: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #1):

1
2
3
          

 

<% @rssfeeds.each do |feed| %>
<li><%= link_to "#{feed.title}", "rssfeeds/#{feed.id}" %></li>
<% end %>

since the variable @rssfeeeds is empty.

Comment: I edited the first port to add the log, it may be more clear than my explaining.

Comment: maybe there is no way to do this the way I like? should I move what I have in layout to another controller?

Comment: Show your both controllers actions, please. I mean these actions where you want to use it.